# What questions are helpful but not upvoted?

Tags: discussion

The honey & lemon diet question ([Does honey with warm water and lemon reduce tummy fat?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/does-honey-with-warm-water-and-lemon-reduce-tummy-fat/22143#22143)) is hugely popular in terms of visits, despite having only moderate upvotes, and was left unanswered for over a year until @rob stepped in and put a bounty on it, drawing it to our attention.

That got me thinking.

**What questions are considered very helpful by anonymous users, but are *relatively* lowly voted?**

My prediction: They will be about popular pseudosciences, such as homeopathy where on-the-fencers stumble on us and visit us, but don't hang around, but which the regulars consider dull/solved issues.

Comment: Hypothesis: Some questions have lots of views because they're the number one hit for a google search, or because they've been slashdotted.

Answer (score 2):

Method:

- Count the number of Helpful votes on each post. (NOTE: This number *excludes*  Unhelpful votes.)
- Produce a table showing the number of helpful votes and the total vote score (NOTE: Total vote score *includes* downvotes as -1)
- Create a scatterplot, expecting to see a nice correlation.
- Compute the ratio of HelpfulVotes/Score, and skim off the top posts.
- Examine posts looking for themes.

Results:

- Scatterplot was a mess. The distributions are dominated by low-voted questions. Even with logarithmic scale, it was hard to see any obvious patterns. Didn't bother pursuing with more analysis.
- Here are the posts that are most disproportionately considered helpful by anonymous users (and logged in users without the privilege to vote):

  1. Q: [Does honey with warm water and lemon reduce tummy fat?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15143)
  2. Q: [Does our brain make ourselves look five times more beautiful than we really are?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7461)
  3. A: [Is this tealight-flowerpot heater more efficient than just tealights?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18338/is-this-tealight-flowerpot-heater-more-efficient-than-just-tealights/18346#18346)
  4. Q: [Was "Gangadhar Nehru" a pseudonym, which he adopted after 1857?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17461)
  5. Q: [Is Paraffinum liquidum (mineral oil) in cosmetics dangerous?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10992)
  6. Q: [Is eating fish  and drinking milk at the same time linked with skin disease?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6719)
  7. Q: [Did William Shakespeare say "I always feel happy..."?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7926)
  8. Q: [Does soursop cure cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7222)
  9. Q: [Is there a place in the world where two oceans meet and they don't mix?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7748)
  10. A: [Does our brain make ourselves look five times more beautiful than we really are?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7461/does-our-brain-make-ourselves-look-five-times-more-beautiful-than-we-really-are/7492#7492)
  11. A: [Can you break a person's neck with a manual head twist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/can-you-break-a-persons-neck-with-a-manual-head-twist/8779#8779)
  12. Q: [Is this picture of Beyoncé Knowles real?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14939)
  13. A: [Is eating fish  and drinking milk at the same time linked with skin disease?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/is-eating-fish-and-drinking-milk-at-the-same-time-linked-with-skin-disease/6736#6736)
  14. A: [Was David Cameron linked to "Hang Nelson Mandela" posters in the 1980s?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/was-david-cameron-linked-to-hang-nelson-mandela-posters-in-the-1980s/16767#16767)
  15. Q: [Are these nude photos of Barack Obama's mother?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11135)
  16. A: [Does drinking from a straw cause excess air in the stomach?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/does-drinking-from-a-straw-cause-excess-air-in-the-stomach/4687#4687)

Conclusion:

- I can't see any obvious themes.  :-( Anyone else?

Comment: Beauty, diet and Beyoncé? Do fans of fashion magazines tend to visit and leave without joining?